# Terminology when referring to bias

Tags: statistics, terminology

I am confused about the way in which I should use the word "bias". Suppose that $r$ is the true value of a variable and $\hat{r}$ is an estimate for $r$. Let $a$ be an arbitrary real number. If $\hat{r}=r+a$, should I refer to $a$ as being the "bias" or the "amount of bias"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That makes no sense whatsoever.  In the frequentist context, you must be absolutely precise about what is random and what is not.

In the frequentist view, **parameters** are fixed (but possibly unknown) quantities that in some sense model the behavior of a random phenomenon.  Outcomes of that random process or phenomenon are observable, but the value of the parameter may not be directly observable.  Therefore, the goal of statistical inference is to **infer** the value of unknown parameter(s) based on observations of the random process.

Here is an example.  Suppose I give you a coin.  I do not tell you whether the coin is fair or unfair.  Inspection of the coin does not reveal to you any information about the probability of obtaining a head or a tail.  The natural thing for you to do is to model the outcome of a coin toss as a Bernoulli random variable with probability of heads equal to some fixed but unknown parameter $p$.  You do this because it is reasonable to assume the chance of getting heads on any given coin toss is not subject to variation.  Whether you toss it today or tomorrow or next week, the coin still has the same probability of heads.  You just don't know what it is.

In this sense, $p$ is **not random**.  In fact, I know what the true value of $p$ is, but I chose not to tell you.  So you conduct an experiment.  You flip the coin $n$ times, and count the **random** number of heads $X$ that is obtained in $n$ trials.  Here, $n$ is fixed, but unlike $p$, it is known to you because you choose how many trials to conduct.

If we regard the result of your experiment as being a set of individual Bernoulli outcomes, then $n$ is the **sample size** of your experiment and $X$ is the **sample total** or sample sum.  If we regard the result of your experiment as being a *single* Binomial observation of $X$ heads, then $n$ is a known parameter of the Binomial distribution.  Both ways lead to the same inference and in either case, your goal is to estimate $p$.

The intuitive thing to do to estimate $p$ is to calculate $X/n$; i.e., this is the **sample mean** (under the Bernoulli interpretation).  That is to say, you may choose the estimate $$\hat p = X/n,$$ which is a function of the sample, which is itself a random variable, and is called a **statistic**.  In simple terms, $\hat p$ is something that you would expect to vary from experiment to experiment.  If you had flipped the coin $n = 7$ times and obtained $X = 3$ heads, your estimate of the probability of heads might be $\hat p = 3/7$, but if the next day you flip the coin $n = 20$ times, you might obtain $X = 11$ heads and your estimate on that day, ignoring the previous outcomes, is $\hat p = 11/20$.  If you were to pool all of your observations, you would estimate $\hat p = (3+11)/(7+20) = 14/27$.  Each of these is different, because the process of flipping the coin and observing an outcome is random, thus your estimate is also going to be random.

So, the fundamental difference is that an **estimator** of a parameter is a statistic, and the estimator is a random variable but the parameter it estimates is not.  Therefore, it makes no sense to say $$\hat p = p + a.$$  The LHS is random; the RHS is fixed.

Furthermore, **bias** refers to the extent to which the expected value of an estimator deviates from the true value of the parameter it estimates.  For example, consider the above estimator $\hat p = X/n$.  This is a "natural" estimator for $p$ but we have not explained why it feels natural to choose it.  After all, we could just as easily have chosen to use the estimator $$\tilde p = \frac{X + 1/2}{n + 1/2} = \frac{2X + 1}{2n + 1}.$$  But remember; an estimator is a random variable, so it has an expected value.  In the first case, we can calculate through the linearity of expectation (or recognizing that $X$ is binomially distributed) that $$\operatorname{E}[\hat p] = \operatorname{E}[X/n] = \operatorname{E}[X]/n = (np)/n = p.$$  Therefore, $\hat p$ is unbiased.  This means that if we conduct many experiments on this coin, whether for small or large sample sizes $n$, on average, the estimates we get from each experiment will tend toward the true value of the parameter.

How about the other estimator $\tilde p$?  We calculate $$\operatorname{E}[\tilde p] = \operatorname{E}\left[\frac{2X+1}{2n+1}\right] = \frac{2\operatorname{E}[X]+1}{2n+1} = \frac{2np+1}{2n+1} \ne p$$ for any $n$.  This estimator therefore must be biased.  The extent of bias is $$\operatorname{Bias}(\tilde p) = \operatorname{E}[\hat p] - p = \frac{2np+1}{2n+1} - p = \frac{1-p}{2n+1}.$$  This tells you that the estimator $\tilde p$ will tend to overestimate the true value of the parameter, but it also tells you that if $n$ is very large, or $p$ is close to $1$, the bias will be small.  Because $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \operatorname{Bias}(\tilde p) = 0,$$ we call this estimator **asymptotically unbiased**.  The bias is allowed to be a function of the parameter as well as the sample size.  But it is not (unconditional on other random variables) itself a random variable.